# We were sleeping or we had been sleeping

Tags: verbs, time-reference

1. Yestarday we were sleeping till 10 a.m. 
   Or
2. Yestarday we had been sleeping till 10 a.m

How should I say this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would typically say *Yesterday we slept till 10 a.m.*

*Were sleeping* wouldn't typically be used with reference to a point in time (although you can use it here), unless the point in time occurs during the period of the ongoing activity. For example:

> Yesterday we were sleeping at 10 a.m.

Meaning that 10 a.m. happened while we were sleeping. In this case, you have to use the progressive. If you say *we slept at 10 a.m.* you would be understood to mean that you went to sleep at 10 a.m.

The progressive is optional if you refer to a period of time:

> Yesterday we slept all morning.
>   Yesterday we were sleeping all morning.

This can be confusing. For example, this is correct:

> What were you doing at 10 a.m. yesterday morning?

The reason that we use the progressive past here is that we are asking about an ongoing activity that includes the specific point in time. You might answer the question like this:

> I was sleeping.

Now, the past *perfect* progressive is only used to refer to an activity that went on for a period in the past and ended later in the past.

> At 10 a.m. yesterday, I had been sleeping for several hours.

You wouldn't say *Yesterday, I had been sleeping until 10 a.m.* because if you do it yesterday, it only occurs once. However, this is correct:

> I had been sleeping until 10 a.m. for several months. Then I found a job, and started getting up at 7 a.m.

In this case, it is the sleeping until 10 a.m. that is the ongoing activity, which ended at a point in the past.